# How to distribute trained model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, exe

I want to distribute my trained deep-learning model which is made using Keras.

The partner want to use it without complicated environment construction, such as installing python, keras, etc...

How can I do this? Should I make an .exe file?

Comment: Look into cx_freeze

Comment: Can you explain more about how your partner will be using it? What type (and what volume) of input data will they be feeding into the model? How are they expecting to receive the output?

Comment: the basic solution is to use model.save(), as described in the current answer. 
this still requires python some dependencies.

if you want to make it more self contained, you need to decide what you want (a service, an api, a batch program) - this will define the specific solution

Comment: @Imran My partner will use it for image recognition by adding it into their software as a component. They give me training data, I train the model and give them the trained model. The trained model receives one or more images and output the classification results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to look into this [tutoiral](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model).

Simplest code possible:

```
from keras.models import load_model

model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'

# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```